# how to display server side errors using jquery unobtrusive validation in mvc

Tags: jquery, ajax, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4

I m making jquery ajax post on a button click and doing unobtrusive form validation as below

```
 $.validator.unobtrusive.parse('#formSite');
 $('#formSite').validate();
 if ($('#formSite').valid()) {

   $.ajax({
        type: "POST",
        url: "/Controller/ActionMethod",
        cache: false,
        content: "application/html; charset=utf-8",
        data: {
            //data
        },
        success: function (data) {
                 if(data.success)
                 {
                 //processing
                 }else
                 {
                    //show errors
                 }
     }
```

The above works perfectly fine for any existing model errors. In my controller I manually add errors in the modelstate and need to parse the form again showing those errors. How can we call `$.validator.unobtrusive.parse('#formSite')` with the additional server side errors and display them. My controller action method looks like this.

```
if (condition)
  {
    ModelState.AddModelError("PostCode", "Postcode District is invalid");
  }
    //processing
var modelErrors = AllErrors(ModelState);
return Json(new { success = false, modelErrors },JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);
```

Comment: You gonna display validation summary or just a single custom validation message??

Comment: What is the actual point of this. If you want to return the view with errors, do a normal submit. And `$.validator.unobtrusive.parse('#formSite');` does not do anything unless you first set the validator to `null` anyway

Comment: @GuruprasadRao I need to show validation summary.

Comment: @Stephen Muecke The way the application is designed I need to use Ajax post, can't do the normal submit and all i m trying to do is to get the errors from the server and display them using jquery unobtrusive validator.

Comment: You cant display them using the validator unless you return the view, replace the form, reset the validator and reparse it (validation works on controls in a form, not on json data). If you want to display a message, then add an `<div>` and update its contents with the error message.

Comment: You can keep a div with `id` say `Error` and write a `$.each` function for errors that gets returned in your `data.modelErrors` and append it to the above div `Error`

Answer (score 1):

Have a look at [Remote Validation](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ie/gg508808(v=vs.98).aspx) this may help you